# Implement Forgot Password in aspnet boilerplate

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to implement Forgot Password with Identity in aspnet boilerplate.

1. I created a new project in visual studio with individual user authentication and implemented and tested forgot password functionality (Project Name: `IdentityProject`).
2. Then I downloaded abp project and copied the `App_Start/AppIdentityConfig.cs` and `IdentityModels` file from `IdentityProject` to `ABPProject`.
3. Write this line in `Startup.cs` class in `Configuration` method: `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);`

Below is my `ApplicationUserManager` class in `IdentityConfig.cs`:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
        };

        //removed some of the  configuration code..

        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}
```

On running application I'm getting exception on first line of `Create` method:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: context
>
> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in
>   user code

While context parameter has this data:
[image]

Below is `ApplicationDbContext` class of identity:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Below is class of `ABPProjectDBContext`:

```
public class HRISDbContext : AbpZeroDbContext<Tenant, Role, User>
{

    public HRISDbContext()
        : base("Default")
    {

    }
    public HRISDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {

    }

    //This constructor is used in tests
    public HRISDbContext(DbConnection existingConnection)
     : base(existingConnection, false)
    {

    }

    public HRISDbContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
     : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
    {

    }
}
```

What could be the reason for this exception and how to solve this?

Comment: Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()` returns null (or looks like it is null).

In your startup.cs you need to add

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationDbContext>(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
```